# Simplifying Square Roots with Fractions?

Tags: fractions

I know this is a very basic question, but could someone please mathematically explain, why this is true:

> $\sqrt{x} \cdot \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$

Wolfram|Alpha can [confirm this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28x%29%2a%281/x%29).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us suppose that $x$ is positive. If it is not, our expression is not defined. Note that essentially by definition,
$$x=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}.$$
It follows that 
$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}.$$
(For the last step, we divided top and bottom by $\sqrt{x}$.)

Comment: Ah... I see. Basically $x = \sqrt{x} \cdot \sqrt{x} = {\sqrt{x}}^{2} = x$. Now it makes sense how the cancellation occurs. Thank you!

Comment: You don't really need to assume $x > 0$, do you?  This is true for any nonzero complex number $x$ and any branch of $\sqrt{x}$.  For that matter, it's true in any ring for any element that has both an inverse and a square root.

Comment: @Robert Israel: True, the $x>0$ stuff could be omitted. But I wanted to remind the OP that, at the level (s)he is working, there are restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{x}\cdot\frac{1}{x}= \color{Red}{\sqrt{x}}\cdot\frac{1}{\color{Red}{\sqrt{x}}\cdot\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}.$$

A more general method: $x^{1/2}\cdot x^{-1}=x^{1/2-1}=x^{-1/2}=(x^{1/2})^{-1}.$